# Grep command to extract parameter values from file

Tags: grep

I am totally new to unix and need some help regarding grep command

I have an output file with 7 parameter values S1, S2..., S7.
How can I use grep command to extract only the values and write them as an array to a new file, which I want to plot later.

```
<<<<< Function evaluation summary (APPROX_INTERFACE_1): 1808 total (1808 new, 0 duplicate)
<<<<< Best parameters          =
                      3.3500000000e+02 S1
                      1.0357218750e+00 S2
                      7.2046250000e+01 S3
                      7.2872921875e+01 S4
                      5.7405507812e+01 S5
                      5.0000054687e+01 S6
                      2.3999984375e+02 S7
<<<<< Best objective function  =
                      8.0674284316e-01
```

Comment: What operating system are you using? Can we assume your `grep` has the `-o` flag? How about the `-P` flag? Also, please [edit] your question and show us the output you are expecting from this input. What are the 7 parameter values? Is `Function` a parameter? Is `APPROX_INTERFACE_1` one? How about 1808? How can we identify the parameters?

Answer (score 0):

Grep is a line selection tool.

```
grep ' S.$' your.txt
```

will give you the lines with the 7 values.

If you need to trim the values from each line you can use cut:

```
grep ' S.$' yout.txt |cut -d ' '  -f23
```

Use 23 if you have 22 spaces in the beggining of each line.

AWK will be a good alternative to both grep and cut.

Answer (score 0):

If we can be sure that what we want is the first field of every line whose second field is a `S` followed by a number, we can do:

```
$ awk '$2~/^S[0-9]$/{print $1}' data
3.3500000000e+02
1.0357218750e+00
7.2046250000e+01
7.2872921875e+01
5.7405507812e+01
5.0000054687e+01
2.3999984375e+02
```

If you want those as values in an array, do:

```
array=( $(awk '$2~/^S[0-9]$/{print $1}' data) )
```

And if you want them in a new file, do:

```
awk '$2~/^S[0-9]$/{print $1}' data > new.data
```

Comment: Thanks. how can I put the values in an array and then store the array in a new file ?

Comment: @MandeepSingh I don't understand why you would want to do both. If you really, really need to, just use `array=( $(awk '$2~/^S[0-9]$/{print $1}' data) )` and then run `printf '%s\n' "${array[@]}" > newFile`. But why not just redirect to a file directly?